# Create encode and decode methods in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, encoding

I'm using the base62 gem for obfuscation/shortening ids.  So I have things like:

```
552.base62_encode
=> "8u"
"8u".base62_decode
=> 552
```

I'd like to alias these in an initializer so they're cleaner, like so:

```
class Fixnum
  def encode
    base62_encode
  end
end

class String
  def decode
    base62_decode
  end
end
```

Are there any issues with using the words `encode` and `decode` directly?  Will this cause problems with any interdependencies, other gems, etc, or is this safe to do?

Answer (score 3):

Well, since the [String#encode](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-encode) method is defined by ruby, yes, it will cause problems.

As a general note, you should run away from monkey patching as fast as you can.
It will only make your applications harder to comprehend for new developers, and harder to maintain.

Comment: You're saying best practice is to never rename things like this?  My goal was to make it more readable.